# Populate HTML Table from javascript array format

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose i have an java script Array in the following format,

```
[
"Heading 1",
"Heading 2",
"Data 1",
"Data 2",
"Data 3",
"Data 4",
 ]
```

I need to make a HTML table from the array in the following format[image]

I've never dynamically created an HTML Table from Javascript.
Can anyone help me out? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you dynamically created *any* type of HTML elements from JS?

Comment: Will your structure always contain two columns? Where do you get the column information?

Comment: You should probably start with a tutorial like [*Traversing an HTML table with JavaScript and DOM Interfaces*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces). Creating a table from your data is quite simple, but giving you the code won't help you much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can find some code to make what you need to:

```js
//set the number of columns (we use 2 because you have 2 "Heading")
var _numberCol = 2,
    _arr = [
      "Heading 1",
      "Heading 2",
      "Data 1",
      "Data 2",
      "Data 3",
      "Data 4"
  ];

//create a table
var $table = document.createElement("table"), $row;

for(var _k = 0; _k < _arr.length; _k++){
   //we create a row when index is divisible for _numberCol
   if(_k % _numberCol===0) $row = $table.insertRow(-1);
   //for each element inside the array we crate a cell inside the current row
   $col = $row.insertCell(-1);
   //then we put the value inside like text
   $col.innerText = _arr[_k];
}

//now we can append our table where we need to place it
document.body.appendChild($table);
```

This code works only with your type of array that has only one dimension, and all Heading are defined like each other cell in the table.

Comment: Your code works, but how do i set the table to a specific DIV @Frogmouth

Comment: I figured it out, document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild($table);

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in JS you can use the array to create an html string for the table. If you then need to put it inside an element in your html page you could do something like:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = myHtmlTable;
```

I wrote an example of a function to generate such a string in [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3ptoc4k/5/).

(Let me know if you can't access the fiddle, I've never used it before for StackOverflow answers).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
"Heading 1",
"Heading 2",
"Data 1",
"Data 2",
"Data 3",
"Data 4",
 ]
 
var tabdiv = document.createElement('div');
tabdiv.setAttribute("id", "tab");
document.body.appendChild(tabdiv)
 document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML = "<table border = '1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>" +'<tr>' + '<th>'+ data[0] + "</th>" + '<th>'+ data[1] + "</th>" + '</tr>' + '<tr>' + '<td>' + data[2] + '</td>' + '<td>' + data[3] + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '<td>' + data[4] + '</td>' + '<td>' + data[5] + '</td>' + '</tr>';
```