# How to make a table from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a variable with data like this

```
[
    [
        {"_hex":"0x00"},
        {"_hex":"0x00"},
        {"_hex":"0x00"}
    ],
    [
        {"_hex":"0x5fd77d24"},
        {"_hex":"0x5fd77d2d"},
        {"_hex":"0x5fd7a39a"}
    ],
    [
        {"_hex":"0x05f5e100"},
        {"_hex":"0x05f5e100"},
        {"_hex":"0x05f5e100"}
    ],
    [
        {"_hex":"0x00"},
        {"_hex":"0x00"},
        {"_hex":"0x00"}
    ],
    [
        false,
        false,
        false
    ]
]
```

I want to show this data in a table like this

```
id        value        quantity      date        vote
3         12132        13434         1564310899  false
2         89183        12342         1564311902  false
2         78172        54321         1564313122  false
```

How can I do this?
I thought about using foreach loop but it would loop through each row.
NB: (I will convert the hex values to decimal too)

Edit:
I have tried using for loop but I get repeated values on all columns.
The solutions suggested do not work for me because the array is arranged differently.

Comment: _"I thought about using foreach loop but it would loop through each row."_ - did you try this?

Comment: If you only want console output `console.table` will get you close.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We encourage users to post their efforts instead of just asking for help. Try yourself at it and don't worry if you fail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populate HTML Table from javascript array format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153200/populate-html-table-from-javascript-array-format)

Comment: @evolutionxbox i do not want console.table and i tried using for loop.

Comment: @DaemonPainter i have attempted to solve it using for loop but i end up getting same value for all columns.

Comment: Show your loop, it will work, you just must have something wrong and we can help you fix it.

Comment: @NKSM the suggested answer has a different arrangement of array

Comment: Please help others so they can help you with your problem instead of saying things dont work.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to calculate the widths of each value, so that each column is the same size.

After you do that, you can simply map your data to rows; delimited by a space or any other character.

```js
const data = [
  [ 'id', 'value', 'quantity', 'date', 'vote' ],
  [ 3, 12132, 13434, 1564310899, false ],
  [ 2, 89183, 12342, 1564311902, false ],
  [ 2, 78172, 54321, 1564313122, false ]
];

const printTable = (data, delimiter) => {
  const widths = data[0].map((col, index) =>
    Math.max(...data.map(row => `${row[index]}`.length)));
  return data.map(row =>
    row.map((col, index) => `${col}`.padEnd(widths[index]))
      .join(delimiter))
    .join('\n');
};

console.log(printTable(data, ' | '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```